# Firefox: open URL by X11-pasting it into browser window

Tags: linux, firefox

I have recently upgraded Firefox to ESR 60.3.0 on my linux box, and lost a convenient ability: it used to be that, if I had a URL copied into the X11 clipboard, a simple middle-click in the (focused or unfocused) browser window would open it in current tab.

I haven't found how to restore this in the `about:config` settings. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` in `about:config`.